# Azure key vault how to identify different identities assigned in access policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-vm-scale-set

I have two VMSS with same name in different resource group , and i see both of them  have managed identities enabled and both are givn access to keyvault i want to remove access to one of the VMSS from keyvault i am not able to differentiate which one belongs to whom, below is screenshot-

[image]

when i click on any one of them it just shows below screenshot

[image]

how can i get the object id to identify exact vmss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Powershell to remove the specific identity

```
Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName '<your keyvault name>' -ObjectID <id for managed identity linked to requrired VMSS>
```

Portal doesn't really provide a way to distinguish as far as I could see. It only shows DirectoryID but from your screenshot it's evident that DirectoryID is probably same for both identities.

To find the unique ObjectID linked to each of your VM Scale Sets, go to Azure Portal > desired virtual machine scale set > Identity.

[image]